Unity "Cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section"
Just restarted my PC and opened up Unity, edited a movement script in VS code, and closed everything after and I am still getting the error:
error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\My project\Library\Bee\artifacts\1900b0aE.dag\Assembly-CSharp.dll' for writing -- 'The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open. : 'C:\My project\Library\Bee\artifacts\1900b0aE.dag\Assembly-CSharp.dll''
already attempted the top solution posted here:
The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open
But it is still giving me the same issue. Does anyone have any other ideas?

id guess you have told unity use some of the quick edit options about not reloading domains and the like so its still running?

Can you try to close Unity (and all programs that might access your files) and delete the Library folder? Library is a cache that will be fully regenerated the next time you open the project in Unity so no worries
